# Excel 2003 according to the values of a cell should be linked to different worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

I have a cell that will have different text values (because it's the choice of a dropdown) according to the chosen value, it needs to be linked to a different worksheet that will preferably have the name of the text value.  I will need to link about 50 names in the dropdown then, there must be a formula VBA that it links me there.

I was putting the result of the dropdown in another cell as =Right, in order to copy the value and make the link from there to the new worksheet, but i'm stack.

this formula works for a specific name, but I need a "general name" to be updated each time a new worksheet is opened:

If Range ("C29").Value="Edgar" Then Sheets("Edgar").Select

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I fully understand your question (for example, I do not understand ‘linked to a different worksheet that will preferably have the name of the text value’ or ‘I need a "general name" to be updated each time a new worksheet is opened’), but this is something that you might be able to do *without* VBA.  If cell `C29` contains the name of a worksheet in the current workbook, and (in some other cell) you want to access the value of cell `Q42` on the sheet named by cell `C29`, use

```
=INDIRECT(C29 & "!Q42")
```

`&` is string concatenation, so this builds the string “Edgar!Q42”.  And the `INDIRECT` function treats that string as a cell reference.

This provides a read-only access: if the user fills in cell `C29` with the value “Edgar” (by selecting from a dropdown, or any other way), then cells on Sheet1 can *display* values from sheet “Edgar”, such as Edgar’s date and place of birth, eye color, etc. 
I chose those examples as things you would never change.  But if your workbook also contains dynamic information like current address and telephone number, height and weight, title and salary, etc., then the user will be able only to look at them.  If you want the workbook to jump to sheet “Edgar”, you will need VBA.  If you want to be able to enter data into cells in Sheet1 and have them copied to sheet “Edgar”, I don’t know whether that can be done at all; but if it’s possible, I’m pretty sure that it will require VBA.

Comment: Scott, Thank you for yr answer. Pls excuse my English. Imagine I have 50 worksheets named Sheet1, Edgar, Lee, Jane... User wants to select the names from a dropdown in Sheet1.  Then get additional info from these people in the worksheets with the name of Edgar, Lee... So by selecting Edgar or Lee on Sheet1 user is taken from Sheet1 to Sheet Edgar or Lee etc.  Can a formula automatically affect new worksheets, or should I do individual entries as formula . Tk

Comment: @Tia if you want the list of sheets updated as you add new - VBA is only option here. You'd better ask it on SO, programming questions are more welcome there.

Comment: Ok!  I thank you for your time and quick response!!