# create a formula that will "dynamically" alter the sheet name from a validation box

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a workbook containing monthly data sheets (sheet 1="January", sheet 2="February", etc.). I also have a "Data Display" sheet where I have endusers select the months summary they would like to see. I'm using a data validation box for user to choose the month. Based upon the end user's selection, I want to have my formula adjust this formula to the appropriate sheet:

```
=SUMIF(January!$Q:$Q,"Total_Controllable_Expenses",January!$S:$S)
```

All of my monthly sheets have the same column assignments.

Comment: See also [this question regarding linking to something according to the value of a cell](http://superuser.com/questions/559467/excel-2003-according-to-the-values-of-a-cell-should-be-linked-to-different-works).

Answer (score 0):

Turn the fixed reference *January* into reference to your validated choice (say in `A1`). Then wrap in an INDIRECT. ie replace both instances of `January` with `INDIRECT(A1&"` and in each case match off (ie close to suit) the quotes and parentheses.

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A1&"!$Q:$Q"),"Total_Controllable_Expenses",INDIRECT(A1&"!$S:$S"))
```